# How to calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n}{n!}$?

Tags: limits

How to calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n}{n!}$?
I tried using $\lim \frac{x^n}{a^x} = 0$ but it didn't work

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77550/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1269562/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/923581/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2562293/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B2%5En%7D%7Bn!%7D%24)

Answer (score 5):

The limit is $0$, since factorial growth is faster than exponential growth.

$$ 2^n/n! = (2/1)*(2/2)*\ldots*(2/n)$$
$$ \leq 2 * 2/n$$

This quantity can clearly be made arbitrarily small for sufficiently large n, hence the limit is 0 (since $2^n/n!$ is positive)

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$2^n = (1 + 1)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.$$
Try to conclude from that.

Comment: Can you give me the ful answer please

Comment: Just look above, there is 2 very good answers.